# why import sklearn is not working in Jupyter?

Tags: scikit-learn, anaconda

I installed the recent version of Anaconda but "Import sklearn" gives an error

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-b7c74cbf5af0> in <module>
----> 1 import sklearn

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     62 else:
     63     from . import __check_build
---> 64     from .base import clone
     65     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     66 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     11 from scipy import sparse
     12 from .externals import six
---> 13 from .utils.fixes import signature
     14 from . import __version__
     15 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     14 from . import _joblib
     15 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
---> 16 from .fixes import _Sequence as Sequence
     17 from .deprecation import deprecated
     18 from .validation import (as_float_array,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>
     90     from ._scipy_sparse_lsqr_backport import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
     91 else:
---> 92     from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
     93 
     94 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
    115 from .dsolve import *
    116 from .interface import *
--> 117 from .eigen import *
    118 from .matfuncs import *
    119 from ._onenormest import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py in <module>
      9 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     10 
---> 11 from .arpack import *
     12 from .lobpcg import *
     13 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py in <module>
     20 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     21 
---> 22 from .arpack import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py in <module>
     43 __all__ = ['eigs', 'eigsh', 'svds', 'ArpackError', 'ArpackNoConvergence']
     44 
---> 45 from . import _arpack
     46 import numpy as np
     47 import warnings

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. I had created an env file for Jupyter and edited it to open jupyter in Chrome. After updating python, import sklearn did not work. So I had to go back and delete that env file and everything worked fine after that. Hope this helps future readers of this post.